# Why is the shape of the legend's elements not the same than the ones on the chart with `ggplot` in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(x = mpg, y = disp, size = cyl) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.99, method = "loess")
```

[image]
As you can see there are *circles* in the charts, but there are *rectangles* in the legend.

How to have circles in the legend as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add `aes` separately, instead you can do this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(level = 0.99, method = "loess")  
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]